# Win 8 MonoGame - Game resolution vs. screen resolution

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, monogame, resolutions

I'm currently working on a Win 8 Windows Store game (Monogame, C#). I set the graphics.PrefferedBackBuffers to 1366x768. The laptop that I use mostly to develop doesn't support this resolution neither does the external monitor connected to it, however everything gets scaled nicely so the sprites are compressed or stretched on different monitors (this doesn't hold if the game is dragged to another monitor while running).
I need to use the mouse to drag game objects around but I notice that the mouse cursor works in the monitor resolution, so doing something like :

```
 if(objectSprite.BoundingBox.Contains((int)mouseCursos.x, (int)mouseCursos.Y))
 {
        objectSprite.isHooked = true;
 }
```

doesn't work since the mouse's coordinates are always different from the coordinates of the game objects. How do I get the current monitor's max resolution so I'll be able to scale the coordinates.

Please note that GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode returns 800x600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Metro app's are generally full-screen by default (although they could be snapped too) you can use the following properties from the Window class:

```
Window.ClientBounds.Width
Window.ClientBounds.Height
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot thank you. However I used Window.ClientBounds.Height/Width, as in my app Window doesn't have Current property but you certainly put me in the right direction.

Comment: That's cool. Its kind of weird though because according to the MSDN documentation it says 'Current' is an available property for the Windows Store-type applications. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.aspx

Comment: I take that back. 'Current' is available in non-Windows Store versions of Win8 apps. I mis-read the documentation. I'll update my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

In my MonoGame Windows Store app ClientBounds somehow doesn't exist, Window.Current somehow is null, so I use this approach:

```
            CoreApplicationView v = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView;
        var bounds = v.CoreWindow.Bounds;
        double w = bounds.Width;
        double h = bounds.Height;
        switch (DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale)
        {
            case ResolutionScale.Scale140Percent:
                w = Math.Round(w * 1.4);
                h = Math.Round(h * 1.4);
                break;
            case ResolutionScale.Scale180Percent:
                w = Math.Round(w * 1.8);
                h = Math.Round(h * 1.8);
                break;
        }
        ScreenSize resolution = new ScreenSize(w, h);
        if (ApplicationView.Value == ApplicationViewState.FullScreenLandscape)
            resolution = new ScreenSize(w, h);
        else if (ApplicationView.Value == ApplicationViewState.FullScreenPortrait)
        {
            resolution = new ScreenSize(h, w);
        }
        else if (ApplicationView.Value == ApplicationViewState.Filled)
        {
            resolution = new ScreenSize(w + 320.0 + 22.0, h); //snapped mode grip
        }
```